Citation prenote - chapter instead of page

I'm using biblatex and citing page numbers on the prenotes.
I notice that, very conveniently, the prenote on ~\autocite[21]{Pereira2022} is rendered as "p. 21" on the references section, while ~\autocite[6-16]{UNDDR2021} is conveniently rendered as "pp. 6-16".
I'd like to do the same for chapter numbers, but don't know how to do the trick. Instead, I'm writing like "chapter 7" on my own language. The automatically rendering of "ch." doesn't happens.

Question: is there a simple code sintax to semantically mention, in the prenote, that the number is of a chapter instead of a page?
Code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    style=numeric,
    sorting=none,
    backend=biber
]{biblatex}

\title{StackExchange}
\author{BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah}
\date{August 2024}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. ~\autocite[21]{Pereira2022}

Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. ~\autocite[6-16]{UNDDR2021}

\printbibliography
\end{document}


Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Fine, I added some code.

This does not seem to produce a bibliography.

You can use pagination = to change the numbering from the default pages to something else for all citations of this work:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    style=numeric,
    sorting=none,
    backend=biber
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{knuth,
  author       = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  title        = {The {\TeX} book},
  date         = 1984,
  maintitle    = {Computers \& Typesetting},
  volume       = {A},
  publisher    = {Addison-Wesley},
  location     = {Reading, Mass.},
  langid       = {english},
  langidopts   = {variant=american},
  sortyear     = {1984-1},
  sorttitle    = {Computers & Typesetting A},
  indexsorttitle= {The TeXbook},
  indextitle   = {\protect\TeX book, The},
  shorttitle   = {\TeX book},
  pagination   = {chapter}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\title{StackExchange}
\author{BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah}
\date{August 2024}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. ~\autocite[21]{knuth}

Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. ~\autocite[6-16]{knuth}

\printbibliography
\end{document}



Interesting. I did not know that this was possible.
